# Is there a way to make untiy AddForce slower?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a jump action slower than it is , `rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpPower);` I am using AddForce in order to move the player in the y axis , when the player is jumping he is getting right to the height point I want him to but not in the right amount of time.
So what I am asking is is there a way to make the player time of jump lower without affecting the height point he can get to?

I tried changing the JumpPower variables but as expected when changing the JumpPower the time is changing but with it the height the player is getting to.

This is my code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody rb;
    public float MouseSensitivity;
    public float MoveSpeed;
    public float JumpPower;
    private Vector3 targetMoveDirection;
    // Smoothing factors
    public float moveSmoothing = 0.1f;
    public float rotateSmoothing = 0.1f;

    bool isJumping = false;



    void Start()
    {
        //Cursor.visible = false;

    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Move
        targetMoveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Vertical") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.AddForce(targetMoveDirection * MoveSpeed, ForceMode.VelocityChange);

        Vector3 newVelocity = rb.velocity;
        newVelocity.x = Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.x, 0, moveSmoothing);
        newVelocity.z = Mathf.Lerp(rb.velocity.z, 0, moveSmoothing);
        rb.velocity = newVelocity;

        // Jump
        if (Mathf.Abs(rb.velocity.y) < 0.01f && !isJumping)
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
            {
                rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * JumpPower);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What data type is `JumpPower`? The [components of a `Vector3` use `float`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-x.html), so if `JumpPower` is `int` it will apply a *lot* of power, but if you use `float` and values less than one, you're likely to see better results.

Comment: do you mean the time will be higher and the height will be the same?

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: I added my code

Comment: Play with gravity.  Less force and less gravity may produce the results you want.